# CF Entity Framework filtering related data

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Using the following example I'm attempting to retrieve all Jobs where IsAssigned is false.

```
public class Job {
  public int JobId { get; set; }
  ...
  public virtual ICollection<Bid> Bids { get; set; }
}

public class Bid {
  public int BidId { get; set; }
  public int JobId { get; set; }
  ...
  public bool IsAssigned { get; set; }
  ...
  public virtual Job Job { get; set; }
}
```

Below is the View method for displaying the available jobs.

```
public ViewResult AvailableJobs() {
  var jobs = db.Jobs.Include(j => j.Bids.Select(b => b.IsAssigned));
  return View(jobs.ToList());
}
```

This produces the following error

A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'MvcTuition.DAL.Bid' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'IsAssigned'.

Any ideas of how I can return all Jobs where IsAssigned is false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var jobs = db.Jobs.Include(j => j.Bids).Where(j => j.Bids.Any(b => b.IsAssigned));
```

Comment: Thanks @Eranga works a charm. I did try something similar but with no luck.

Comment: @SeanDooley This will return all bids for jobs that have at least one assigned bid, not only assigned bids of all jobs. It this what you meant by "filtering related data"?

Answer (score 1):

```
var jobs = db.Jobs.Include(j => j.Bids.Where(b => b.IsAssigned));
```